# Margins of ImageView inside LinearLayout inside inherited RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, inheritance, margins

```
<br.application.component.HexagonGrid
    android:id="@+id/hexagonGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchResultList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</br.application.component.HexagonGrid>
```

`HexagonGrid` was created to put elements inside, like a `RelativeLayout`, this way:

```
public class HexagonGrid extends RelativeLayout {
    public HexagonGrid(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HexagonGrid(Context context, AttributeSet aSet) {
        super(context, aSet);
    }

    [...]

    private ImageView createGrayHexagonDefault() {
        ImageView grayHexagon = new ImageView(context);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins( 10, 0, 10, 0 );
        grayHexagon.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        grayHexagon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hexagon_disabled));
        grayHexagon.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return grayHexagon;
    }
}
```

And I am adding some images programmatically inside this `searchResultList` that is inside `HexagonGrid`.

```
LinearLayout searchResultList= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchResultList);
searchResultList.addView(createGrayHexagonDefault());
```

I am not understanding why `setMargins` is not working:

```
lp.setMargins( 10, 0, 10, 0 );
```

Any one can tell me why?

Comment: I would try to enable "Show layout bounds" in Developer options to see if there are margins set or not.

Comment: I tried it, but `ImageView`'s margins did not appear. @traninho, please help me!

Comment: Could you just try to not call grayHexagon.setLayoutParams(lp); and searchResultList.addView(grayHexagon); and instead of this call searchResultList.addView(grayHexagon, lp); ?

Comment: @traninho I just tried it, but unfortunately unsuccessful.

Comment: And on which place are you setting the margins? Could you share the whole HexagonGrid class?

Comment: @traninho I added it to the answer! **Edit 1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG!

`ImageView` will have a `LinearLayout` as its parent, but there is two types of `LayoutParams`:

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

For some reason, my project automatically selected `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` as default. This way margins don't work.